# How to make a new blockchain from scratch

Tags: blockchain

In the same vein as setting up a private DNS root server and using whatever domain names you want, how do you generate your own blockchain and mine your own coins?

P.S. I don't want any answers like "why would you want to?"  I want to do it **because it can be done**

Comment: There's never going to be a tutorial for something so non-standard. Go read the code and learn how to make a new genesis block, otherwise, you're out of luck.

Comment: translation: I don't know - go figure it out yourself

Comment: Did you figure it out? Maybe you can share your learning and code. Thanks

Answer (score 13):

I think I Found it.  Someone wrote a C program to generate a genesis block.  Code is on github here:

https://github.com/Gnaf/GenesisBlockZero

The original code was pulled from a discussion on the bitcoin developer forums:

https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=187888.

Compile and run the program to generate the initial SHA256 hash, the time and nonce, then plug those into the bitcoin main.cpp source and recompile.  I *think* that's all you have to do to start a new blockchain.

Answer (score 7):

You can do this really easily with [MultiChain](http://www.multichain.com/), and even make your blockchain permissioned, i.e. only accessible to certain entities.

Comment: I can attest to this, multichain has a robust codebase for building blockchains. Still early days, but in my analysis of 20+ codebases, multichain / coinspark are the heavy hitters.

Answer (score 2):

http://build-a-co.in/
You can find all you want and very specific changes

Answer (score 0):

You would want to use [Testnet in a box](http://sourceforge.net/projects/bitcoin/files/Bitcoin/testnet-in-a-box/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like Multichain to build the basic blockchain part of it. You can see my article on how to use Multichain
[here](https://www.computerical.ml/blockchain/building-your-own-blockchain)

Comment: There is a above answer with your same answer.

Comment: For the record, even though this answer is similar to another, I'd like to see it kept since it has a different set of instructions at the given link that may be useful.